# How to convert an OFDM symbol to a signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, ofdm

How can I convert an OFDM symbol generated from an IFFT block to an OFDM signal for the purpose of transmitting it?

Comment: there's no conversion necessary

Answer (score 0):

I think if you added more details about your signal and the specifications of your hardware, that would be helpful to help you in that issue.

What you basically need is to multiply it by carrier signal and take the real part of the resulted signal, after that you need to do the inverse at the receiver end.  You might need also to upsample and use such filter equivalent to your system specifications.

Again, I think if you added more details about your system, we can also give you more information which may guide you.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how would you transmit continuous time waveforms corresponding to IFFT blocks output, then, you need to look at DAC. You will have to add Cyclic prefix if channel is multi-tap to mitigate ISI and then these samples would be input to DAC after some filtering for pulse shaping.
DAC will convert these discrete complex samples to Analog waveforms for transmitting.

Answer (score 0):

1.- I recommend you read this Mathworks white paper:

Bridging Wireless Communications Design and Testing with MATLAB

https://uk.mathworks.com/campaigns/offers/bridging-wireless-communications-design-and-testing-with-matlab.html

2.- OFDM would you please be a bit more specific?

You said you aim at generating a 'signal' and such request includes a really wide term referring to the type of modulation you need the signal to have. OFDM signals have many different parameters.

3.- What band should the carriers occupy?

How much frequency spacing do you need each carrier to have with adjacent carriers?

How many pilots? steady pilots or shifting?

4.- The modulation is just one critical, yet nevertheless just one point, to solve when generating signals.

Should it be compliant to for instance wifi standard?

6.- Wired? wireless? by this I mean do you also need to select signal transducer?

Anyway Mathworks has a complete solution to generate all sorts of real time or just recorded signals, from bits to waves.

7.- If you have [Keysight](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/home.html) [Tektronix](https://www.tek.com/en) [Rohde&Schwarz](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/uk/home_48230.html) [Anritsu](https://www.anritsu.com/en-gb/) [Advantest](https://www.advantest.com/) .. (among others) test equipment, they now come with applications to build custom signals in an external computer, or even in the same test equipment if it's a good generator or tester, and directly produce for instance a test signal with the modulation you choose and using 'all ones' or 'all zeros' or a pseudo-random sequence.

If you buy them equipment they may even help you write code to send your 'signal in a file' or real-time baseband stream to the generator or exciter.

Hope it helps